# .htaccess redirect domain.com/whatever to domain.com/ index.html?domain=whatever

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can i redirect from:

`domain.com/whatever`

To

`domain.com/login.html?domain=whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy, you didn't search enough I think.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.html?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! pretty close, when i type domain .com/whatever
it goes to login.html but it doesn't passes the variable ?domain=whatever

Comment: As per rule it should be there. How are you checking whether `?domain=whatever` is not there? To verify make last rule as: `RewriteRule (.+) index.html?domain=$1 [L,QSA,R]` to see what is URL in browser